# IE 7 display bug and jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've run into an issue I've never seen before with the browser we all know and love. On this page - http://weresayingido.com/register - the labels and help text don't display normally in IE. However, flashing the Datepicker quickly using the following code causes all the text to render normally.

```
// IE detection hackery
if ('\v' == 'v') {
  // Flash the Datepicker UI
  $('input[name="date"]').focus();
  $('input[name="date"]').blur();
  setTimeout("$('body').mousedown()", 1);
}
```

(Yes, the setTimeout is necessary, otherwise the Datepicker block just stays there. No, I don't know why that is, but I would love to know.)

Given that this is by all means a rather hacky hack, I'm wondering *why* this happens and if it's possible to replicate without using this trickery, particularly using just CSS/HTML. Anyone happen to know the answers to these?

**tl;dr:** Something jQuery UI Datepicker is doing is forcing text to render visibly in IE 7 that otherwise doesn't. Can I fix this with just CSS/HTML?

**Relevant links:**

- Page fixed using jQuery Datepicker: http://weresayingido.com/register
- Page rendered without the Datepicker hack: http://weresayingido.com/manage/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 doesn't like `visibility`, and doesn't consider `body` a real element.

Keep your page visible (which is also better for the unfortunate non-JavaScript users you may have). If you absolutely must, use `body {display: none;}` in your style.css, and make it visibly via `$('body').show()` in your script.js. Stay away from `visibility`.

Cheers.

Comment: I swapped that `visibility` bit over to my content element and it appears to be working just fine - apparently it was just however it treats `body` mucking things up. Also, thanks for pointing out the non-JS bit - I hadn't really given much thought to it because, really, who doesn't have JS turned on? But it's probably worth the FOUC to make sure anyone can use it. Any idea why the Datepicker thing was fixing the visibility issue, though? Still don't quite get that one.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but the datepicker refreshes the body element (or adds an additional class, which forces a refresh). Anyhow, good to hear it works!